Удалить значение (город) из Кортежа
всем хорошего вечера. А получается из кортежа мы не можем удалить значение если оно там есть? так как кортеж это не изменяемый тип данных.. Правильно ли я сделал? положил значения в список, удалил оттуда город - значение? и потом положил его в кортеж, или можно как-то оптимизировать его?

from time import ctime

# cities = 'Воронеж Самара Тольятти Ульяновск Пермь'
cities = 'Саиара Москва Вологда Димитровград'
# cities = 'Ульяновск Казань Омск Воронеж Смоленск'


print(cities)

cities = cities.split()
print(cities)

gr = 'Ульяновск'

for items in cities:
    if gr in items:
        cities.remove(gr)
        break

print(*tuple(cities))


---

Тут получается чисто из академических целях в качестве учебы.. Учусь на Степике.. дошли до кортежей.. 

задача надо удалить из списка (кортежа) город Ульяновск.. 
получается что из самого кортежа удалить нельзя, т.е что я сделал.. сделал список, удалил, и потом вывод положил в кортеж, и есть уверенность что это неправильно, что можно сделать как то прощее и производительнее.. 
 


Так у вас изначально строка, а не кортеж. Получается вы из строки сделали список, потом превратили список в кортеж и распечатали кортеж...

да, а список сделал надо было город удалить из него. так понял кортеж это делать не умеет..

cities = ('Ульяновск','Казань', 'Омск', 'Воронеж', 'Смоленск')
gr = 'Ульяновск'
res = (i for i in cities if i!= gr)
print(type(res))
res = tuple(res)
print(res)
print(type(res))


<class 'generator'>
('Казань', 'Омск', 'Воронеж', 'Смоленск')
<class 'tuple'>


а что это за запись? это генератор кортежа получается?

@Alexey Sinitsky Пояснил в ответе

понял т.е. получается генератор и потом переопределяем его в кортеж.

@Alexey Sinitsky можно сразу, в одной строке, не обязательно конвертировать в список, потом в кортеж, просто создать новый кортеж какой нужно. Но можно и работать со списком, потом преобразовать в кортеж

понял, благодарю))
